# Circular Includes with inner classes

Tags: c++, include, inner-classes

I'm having an issue wrapping my head around circular include problems and in particular that I'm currently dealing with.  I have two classes/structs each in their own files.  Class A has an inner class and class B has a member of that type. I need to use instances of B within A which would be ok if they were delcared in the same file but since they're not how can I make this work?

A.h

```
#pragma once

#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
    class Inner{};
    
    B getNewB() { return B{}; }
};
```

B.h

```
#pragma once

#include "A.h"

struct B
{
    A::Inner inner;
};
```

Comment: You can't. Something has to give and be replaced with a reference. Even in the same file you won't be able to make this work because A must be defined before B and B must be defined before A..

Answer (score 0):

A.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "innerA.h"

struct B;

class A
{
public:
    B getNewB();

    friend class InnerA;
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

B A::getNewB() { return B{}; }
```

B.h

```
#pragma once

#include "innerA.h"

struct B
{
    InnerA inner;
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
```

InnerA.h

```
#pragma once

class InnerA
{
};
```

InnerA.cpp

```
#include "innerA.h"
```

I moved `A::Inner` to another class and add friend relation (You can add bidirectional, use same trick as above I with struct declaration)